# Multiple pages for the same keyword on Serpstat report

Tags: search-results, rank-checkers, serpstats

Would Serpstat show the new URLs (with the same keyword) on the rank tracker?

For example

- /home/forhotel
- /hotel-booking-engine

Both targetting the same keyword - "Hotel Booking Engine"

Will the Serpstat report shows two records? or It will pick the page with a higher ranking?

[image]